# How Can I Process Data From "$this->request->getRawInput()" CodeIgniter4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

this is my ajax method that create a form data from an html table

$('#updateStudentInfoBtn').click(function(e){

```
// var delcare
let studentUUID = $('[name=studentUUID]').val();
let apiUrl = "/api/students/studentUUID";
var formObj = {
    firstname : $('[name="firstname"]').val(),
    middlename : $('[name="middlename"]').val(),
    lastname : $('[name="lastname"]').val(),
    gender : $('[name="gender"] option:selected').val(),
    dob : $('[name="dob"]').val(),
    admission_date : $('[name="admission_date"]').val(),
    admission_stage : $('[name="admission_stage"]').val(),
    current_stage : $('[name="current_stage"]').val(),
    current_section : $('[name="current_section"]').val(),
    name_of_guardian : $('[name="name_of_guardian"]').val(),
    relationship_to_student : $('[name="relationship_to_student"]').val(),
    occupation : $('[name="occupation"]').val(),
    phone_no : $('[name="phone_no"]').val(),
};

var form_data = new FormData();

for ( var key in formObj ) {
    form_data.append(key, formObj[key]);
}

$.ajax({
    method: "PUT",
    url: apiUrl,
    data: form_data,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(res){
        response = JSON.stringify(res);
        if(response.status == 201) {
            // show success alert
        }

        //location.href="/admin/allstudents";
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

});

and this is my php script to retrieve the data sent over put method; have omitted the class part.

```
public function update($studentUuid = null)
{
    $studentModel = new StudentModel();
    $studentData = $studentModel->where('uuid',  $studentUuid)->first();

    $input = $this->request->getRawInput();
    return print_r($input);
}
```

the result of print_r give me this text i dont know how to process the data ::

Array ( [------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "firstname" Phinehas ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="middlename" Toast ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastname" Mord ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gender" Female ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dob" Saturday November 11, 1989 ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="admission_date" Thursday May 10, 2001 ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="admission_stage" class 6 ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="current_stage" form 3 ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="current_section" yellow ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name_of_guardian" DR S.K Sapaa ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="relationship_to_student" Father ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="occupation" Manager ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea Content-Disposition: form-data; name="phone_no" xxx-xxx-xxxx ------WebKitFormBoundaryQFcTXWiBZMLhD6ea-- )

Comment: my route is a resource route from the ci4 docs. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for testing use postman  so donwload it

second if json request set request postman to put

but if formDAta reqeust set request post then add this filed
to form data value

```
var form_data = new FormData();

//this works for you
    form_data.append('_method', 'PUT');
```

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/methodspoofing.html

```
for ( var key in formObj ) {
    form_data.append(key, formObj[key]);
}
 form_data.append('_method', 'PUT');


$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: apiUrl,
    data: form_data,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(res){
        response = JSON.stringify(res);
        if(response.status == 201) {
            // show success alert
        }

        //location.href="/admin/allstudents";
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: check solved i need ranks please

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, no idea if it is the right solution for every case but it works for me... I created a helper file (to hide the ugliness) which extracts the values into a regular associative array:

put_helper.php:

```
function getPut($raw_input)
{
    $input_string = $raw_input[array_keys($raw_input)[0]];

    preg_match('#\{(.*?)\}#', $input_string, $match);

    $json_string = '{' . $match[1] . '}';

    $data = (array) json_decode($json_string);

    return $data;
}`
```

and in my controller:

```
public function update($id = null)
{
    helper('put_helper');

    $data = getPut((array) $this->request->getRawInput());
```

`

I couldn't find any other solution on the web ...

hope it helps someone out ;)

Answer (score 0):

to get formDAta() use

```
$this->request->getPost('item');
```

that works for json or formData request body

```
$raw=(array)$this->request->getVar()
```

Comment: both returns empty data array only, the request api is shown. and remember it the method is a PUT method not POST